# Should we have tags for food groups?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have many tags about nutrition: [nutrition](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) [protein](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protein) [vitamins-and-minerals](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vitamins-and-minerals) [iron](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron)

But we have very few tags for food groups: [fruits](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fruits) [seeds](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seeds)

So it seems that the focus is this site is placed very heavily on [nutritionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutritionism) which is a reductionist approach to health (as opposed to a holistic approach which places less emphasis on chemical analysis). Having recognized that built-in bias, are we okay with that? Or do we want to embrace other points of view?

Would it hurt to add tags for food groups? [beans](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beans) [leafy-greens](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leafy-greens) [grains](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grains) [nuts](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nuts)